# How we can find an equivalent of $\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2^i} $

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, summation

How can we find an equivalent of the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2^i}$$

Because using integrals I have been recently able to determine equivalences for a lot of sums using Riemann's theorem (sum to intgeral) but I'm not able to tackle this one. Any help, suggestions?

Comment: what about now !

Comment: Sorry, 3AM might be to late for doing maths :)

Comment: I highly doubt a closed form exists.

Comment: Maybe it's more likely to find an equivalent infinity than an exact equivalent?

Comment: I do not think that a closed form exists but it could be write as $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$ where the terms satisfy the recurrence relation $a_{i+1}=a_i^2$ with $a_0=2$.

Answer (score 2):

With Stolz-Cesaro, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2^i}\sim 2^{2^n}$.

Comment: What does $\sim$ mean here?

Comment: Typically, $\sim$ denotes asymptotic equivalence in this context.